# How to filter Azure ApplicationInsights client-side browser routes by wildcard routes

Tags: angularjs, azure-application-insights

I currently have an Angular 1.x client-side application and I'm trying to send page views to Azure ApplicationInsights when the route changes.  When I go to the Browser -> Funnel section in the portal, all the routes are there, unfortunately, it is not very usable since individual id's which are part of the route all get individual page views.

Is there a way to filter out id's or create a wildcard page view?

[image: wildcard route azure applicationinsights]

Comment: so you want to make a funnel that would be like (1) any page view where name starts with "(Application Root)", (2) any page view where name startswith "(Application Root)/login" (3) any page view where name startswith "(Application Root/projects" or something like that?  that seems entirely reasonable.  forwarded to the team who owns this, to verify.